# shell script does not continue after npm run build command

Tags: bash, shell, npm

I have written a shell script, `deploy.sh`, to deploy a `VueJS` application to the production or development (for testing and QA) server. Before the application is deployed, this script will first generate a `dist` folder through `npm run build`, then copies the `dist` folder to the respective production or deveopment server.

This script takes 4 required options and each option a required argument.

The 4 required options are:

- `t` - type of deployment 'prod' or 'dev'
- `i` - IP address of server to deploy application to
- `f` - folder to deploy in `/var/www/html` of `nginx` server
- `p` - path to `.pem` file for authentication against production or development server

This is how my script is ran `./deploy.sh -t dev -i 12.345.67.890 -f my-folder -p ~/.ssh/DevServerCredentials.pem`.

In one section of this shell script, I have the following to generate the `dist` folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use this script to deploy app to production or development server

curdir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

usage() {
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: ./deploy.sh -t [ prod | dev ] -i [ server-IP-to-deploy-to ] -f [ folder-in-server-to-deploy-to ] -p [ pem-file-location ]"
    echo ""
    echo "Example:"
    echo "  Development Server >> ./deploy.sh -t dev -i 12.345.67.890 -f my-dev-folder -p ~/.ssh/DevServerCredentials.pem"
    echo "  Production Server >> ./deploy.sh -t prod -i website.domain-name.com -f my-prod-folder -p ~/.ssh/ProdServerCredentials.pem"
    echo ""
    exit 2
}

set_variable() {
    local varname=$1
    shift
    if [ -z "${!varname}" ]; then
        eval "$varname=\"$@\""
    else
        echo "Error: $varname already set"
        usage
    fi
}

while getopts 't:i:f:p:?h' c; do
    case $c in
        t) set_variable type $OPTARG ;; 
        i) set_variable ip $OPTARG ;;
        f) set_variable folder $OPTARG ;;
        p) set_variable pem $OPTARG ;;
        h) usage ;;
    esac
done

# checks for wrong and missing arguments
if [ "$type" != 'prod' ] && [ "$type" != 'dev' ] ; then
    echo "Wrong argument given: -t accepts either 'prod' or 'dev'."
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$type" ]; then
    echo "Missing argument: -t argument is missing."
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$ip" ]; then
    echo "Missing argument: -i argument is missing."
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$folder" ]; then
    echo "Missing argument: -f argument is missing."
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$pem" ]; then
    echo "Missing argument: -p argument is missing."
    usage
    exit 1
fi

# set remote server home directory
if [ "$type" = "prod" ] ; then
    homedir=/home/ubuntu
    user=ubuntu
elif [ "$type" = "dev" ] ; then
    homedir=/home/ec2-user
    user=ec2-user
else
    echo "type is neither 'prod' nor 'dev'"
fi

# generate dist folder to be copied to server
if [ "$type" == 'prod' ]; then
    echo "execute npm run build using environment variables from .env.production.local"
    npm run build
fi

if [ "$type" == 'dev' ]; then
    echo "execute npm run build-test using environment variables from .env.test.local"
    npm run build-test
fi

scp -r -i $pem $curdir/../dist $user@$ip:/$homedir/temp

if [ "$folder" = "/" ] ; then
    ssh -t -i $pem $user@$ip "
        dir=\$PWD;
        mv \$dir/temp/index.html \$dir;
        mv \$dir/temp \$dir/dist;

        sudo cp -r \$dir/dist /var/www/html
        sudo cp -r \$dir/index.html /var/www/html
        rm -rf \$dir/*
    "
else
    ssh -t -i $pem $user@$ip "
        dir=\$PWD;
        mkdir \$dir/$folder;
        cd \$dir/$folder;
        mkdir dist

        mv \$dir/temp/index.html \$dir/$folder;
        mv \$dir/temp/* \$dir/$folder/dist;
        rm -rf \$dir/temp;

        sudo cp -r \$dir/$folder /var/www/html
        rm -rf \$dir/*
    "
fi
```

The following is the `package.json` file:

```
{
.
.
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "build-test": "vue-cli-service build --mode test",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
    },
.
.
}
```

Depending on the argument passed to `t` option, it runs its respective `npm` command to generate a `dist` folder that will be deployed to the production or development server accordingly.

The problem I have is that, the shell script **pauses** after the `npm` command and subsequently timed out and exits thus the `dist` folder is not copied to the server.

The section on the shell script that copies the `dist` folder to the server occurs after the `npm` command is ran.

How should my shell script be edited such that it continues after the `npm` command completes?

From what I have read and understood, `sh` scripts can be ran using `npm` scripts which also accepts arguments with workarounds though `npm` does not inherently support this feature. Also through `npm`, I will have to pass the argument values to `npm` and then to the `sh` script. This seems to be a spot opened to bugs in my deployment `sh` script.

I would prefer to achieve what is intended through the `sh` script instead of through `npm`.

Comment: Without knowledge of what `npm run build` is doing we can only speculate, but the symptoms vaguely sound like it's expecting input. What happens if you do `npm run build </dev/null`?

Comment: Also maybe you want to discover the `case` statement.

Comment: @tripleee i have updated my question. essentially, `npm run build` are in-built commands by `VueJS` which generates the `dist` folder of the application. and yes i have tried `npm run build </dev/null`, the operation got timed out after a while too.

Comment: If it pauses *after* this, maybe also show the next line of code? Have you tried tracing with `bash -x` (or `sh -x` if this is a proper Bourne shell script)?

Comment: Try changing your npm script named `build` (or `build-test`) to something really simple, such as `"build": "echo \"hello world\""` - it may help to determine whether the `vue-cli-service ...` command specified in _package.json_ is causing the shell script to pause (perhaps it some long running process that doesn't exit !), or whether it's something within `deploy.sh` itself.  If you conclude that it's the latter is the cause then (as per @tripleee 's suggestion ) [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59245113/edit) your question to show us the next line(s) of code in `deploy.sh`.

Comment: @RobC i tried your suggestion and changed the `npm` script to `"build-test": "echo 'building test version'"`. The script continued and did not pause. I have also updated my question and placed my entire script in the question. sorry for the many `if else` statements in the script. my first attempt at writing a `sh` script. will look into using `case` statements instead.